# Creating an array with mutable data type

Tags: java, mutable

```
**Initializing an array of NaturalNumbers with values 1 through 4**
```

When I debug, I find the array = [5,5,5,5] and my goal is that the array = [1,2,3,4].

```
        NaturalNumber[] array = new NaturalNumber[4];
        NaturalNumber count = new NaturalNumber2(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = count;

            count.increment();
```

Here is a link to all the methods that can be used with natural numbers. I just do not understand how can I create the wanted array without changing `count`'s value.

http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/software/common/doc/index.html?components/naturalnumber/NaturalNumber.html

Comment: You will absolutely, unavoidably have to make copies of the value.

Comment: You should create the object in the for loop not outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NaturalNumber[] array = new NaturalNumber[4];
        NaturalNumber count = new NaturalNumber2(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            count = new NaturalNumber2(i);
            count.increment();
            array[i] = count;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Initializing an array of NaturalNumbers with values 1 through 4**
```

You can do it this way as well

```
int[] numbers = IntStream.range(1, 5).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You got 5,5,5,5 because you are using a boxed non-primitive type instead of a primitive.

So references to `NaturalNumber count` are to the location of an object.  When you put that `count` into the array, you are putting the reference (four copies) and it contains the last value.  Since you do an increment as the very last thing in the last go-through the loop, it points to a value 5 (but is not the value 5).

If you declared `int count` instead and used `count++` since you can't call `.increment ()` on a primitive, then you'd get the sequence 1, 2, 3, 4.  The run-time engine would put the actual value of count at each time into the array.